# How to find non official installed packaged?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian, apt-get

How do I find all installed packages that are not from the official Ubuntu repository?

Some of the packages might have been installed with `dpkg -i ...`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about package management rather than programming. You might have more luck on [sf] or [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility called `apt-show-versions` in the Ubuntu repo that shows you the versions of programs in the Ubuntu archive. So running

```
apt-show-versions | grep 'No available version'
```

would pick up anything that wasn't installed by a repository.

Answer (score -1):

On Fedora I do this `rpm -qi` to get the package info. There must be something similar options in `dpkg`

```
[root@Shash ~]# rpm -qi perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.31-293.fc20.x86_64 
Name        : perl-Scalar-List-Utils
Version     : 1.31
Release     : 293.fc20
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sat 10 May 2014 06:41:29 PM IST
Group       : Development/Libraries
Size        : 81706
License     : GPL+ or Artistic
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Sat 17 Aug 2013 01:28:36 AM IST, Key ID 2eb161fa246110c1
Source RPM  : perl-Scalar-List-Utils-1.31-293.fc20.src.rpm
Build Date  : Fri 16 Aug 2013 10:05:41 PM IST
Build Host  : buildvm-06.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Fedora Project
Vendor      : Fedora Project
URL         : http://search.cpan.org/dist/Scalar-List-Utils/
Summary     : A selection of general-utility scalar and list subroutines
Description :
This package contains a selection of subroutines that people have expressed
would be nice to have in the perl core, but the usage would not really be
high enough to warrant the use of a keyword, and the size so small such
that being individual extensions would be wasteful
```

.

## Probably this is the one your looking for

> `dpkg -p {package}`   Display details about package package group, version, maintainer,  > Architecture, display depends packages, description etc    `dpkg -p lsof`

NOTE: You've to write a script to query and find non-offical package